# How can I have left- and right-aligned content at the same horizontal position in a Bulma modal footer?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have a modal card in Bulma, and I want to have a left-aligned p tag on one side of the footer, and a right-aligned p tag on the other side, occupying the same horizontal space.  The standard classes, like level and columns, don't seem to function correctly in the footer.  I have tried a lot of approaches, but this is the most recent.

```
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <div id="site-type-div" class="columns is-inline-flex">
          <p id="chart-footer" class="level-item">Content</p>
          <p id="site-type-p" class="level-item">Type</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

The two p tags show up in the same horizontal space, but both are left aligned; I want the first on the left and the second on the right.

Comment: use css like : `#site-type-p{text-align:right;}` ?

Comment: No dice - the content doesn't move.  Maybe related to flexbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work? (seems the `modal-card-foot` class doesn't play well with stuff like level and columns)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" /> 
    <footer class="">
      <div id="site-type-div" class="level is-mobile">
          <p id="chart-footer" class="level-left">Content</p>
          <p id="site-type-p" class="level-right">Type</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Added the `is-mobile` as the snippet is small width and otherwise would display it one under the other.

Update:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" /> 
    <footer class="modal-card-foot" style="justify-content: space-between;">
      <div id="site-type-div" class="">
          <p id="chart-footer" class="">Content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="site-type-div" class="">
          <p id="site-type-p" class="">Type</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Seems you need to change the `modal-card-foot` style to use the `justify-content: space-between;` and divide them into 2 divs. 
Info from [is-pulled-right in modal-card-footer](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/516)

Comment: Well, they do show up aligned as I like, but removing the modal-card-foot class also makes the background transparent (which is exciting, but not what I want).  This seems like progress, though - maybe I can just manually style the footer instead of using the Bulma class.